# How to Register the Webhook URL needed for Group Install notifications on Facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to be notified whenever a group admin has installed my app on their group.

I am following the instructions [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/guides#get-webhooks-for-groups-who-install-uninstall-your-app)

Now, the issue is I can't seem to locate the page where I need to register the Webhook URL on my Facebook App Dashboard so I will get a notification for **group_install**.

Any pointers?

Comment: If you don't see the Webhook tab in your app dashboard, then you probably need to add the product "Webhook" first of all.

Comment: @CBroe I have seen the Webhook tab but now I am getting another issue during the process of validating my Webhook URL. During validation Facebook is sending back the error message ```The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="46581558", received="success"```

I am returning success with status code 200 whenever the url is called.
Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: You are not supposed to respond with "success" as the response _body_, but with the actual challenge value. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started

Comment: Ok @CBroe Thank you. But I am using expressjs and here is how I tried accessing the hub. challenge from the query ```let hubChallenge = req.query["hub.challenge"];``` but hubChallenge keeps giving me undefined.

Comment: Can't tell what could be wrong from just that one line.